# How to use bulk collect for loop with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement where header is repeating for each line from source table. I have to create plsql procedure to insert them to separate header and line tables with common identifier. I'm currently using simple for loop construct with if else conditions to maintain unique identified (invoiceid) across header and line table

### Ex: source table

| Invnum | linetype | amount | linenumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ITEM | 100 | 1 |
| 123 | TAX | 20 | 2 |
| 446 | ITEM | 100 | 1 |
| 446 | ITEM | 100 | 2 |
| 446 | TAX | 20 | 3 |

### Header table

| InvId | InvNum | Amt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 123 | 120 |
| 101 | 446 | 220 |

### Line table

| InvId | linetype | amount | linenumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | ITEM | 100 | 1 |
| 100 | TAX | 20 | 2 |
| 101 | ITEM | 100 | 1 |
| 101 | ITEM | 100 | 2 |
| 101 | TAX | 20 | 3 |

I tried simple forloop construct with if else conditions.But is there any better way to do this

Comment: Please [edit] the question and explain: what your sample data is; what the expected output is; and describe in English (not code), the logic you would use to get from the sample data to the expected output. At the moment, I am unclear what the problem is and whether you are starting with 1, 2 or 3 tables of data and which of those tables would be your expected output. Additionally, none of the tables you have shared have the `invoiceid` column that you mention in the initial paragraph.

Comment: Although the request was correctly tagged with Oracle and PL/SQL, I've added the SQL tag, because this can be solved with SQL statements alone. If you want PL/SQL, you can always wrap the SQL in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood it, you need a join, not a loop.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  source (invnum, linetype, amount, linenumber) as
  3    (select 123, 'ITEM', 100, 1 from dual union all
  4     select 123, 'TAX' ,  20, 2 from dual union all
  5     select 446, 'ITEM', 100, 1 from dual union all
  6     select 446, 'ITEM', 100, 2 from dual union all
  7     select 446, 'TAX' ,  20, 3 from dual
  8    ),
  9  header (invid, invnum, amt) as
 10    (select 100, 123, 120 from dual union all
 11     select 101, 446, 220 from dual
 12    )
```

Query that produces that result:

```
 13  select h.invid, s.linetype, h.amt, s.linenumber
 14  from header h join source s on s.invnum = h.invnum
 15  order by h.invid, s.linenumber;

     INVID LINE        AMT LINENUMBER
---------- ---- ---------- ----------
       100 ITEM        120          1
       100 TAX         120          2
       101 ITEM        220          1
       101 ITEM        220          2
       101 TAX         220          3

SQL>
```

---

If it has to be a PL/SQL procedure, just move that piece of code in there; for example:

```
create or replace procedure p_line is
begin
  insert into line_table (invid, line, amt, linenumber)
  select h.invid, s.linetype, h.amt, s.linenumber
  from header h join source s on s.invnum = h.invnum;
end;
/
```

Now, you can modify it and add parameters ("insert only desired `invid` rows") and similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two inserts. As both query the same data set, they get the same invnums, from which you can safely create the invids with `DENSE_RANK` (or even `ROW_NUMBER`, when you aggregate per invnum).

```
insert into header_table (invid, invnum, amt)
select
  row_number() over (order by invnum) + 99,
  invnum,
  sum(amount)
from source_table
group by invnum;
```

and

```
insert into line_table (invid, linetype, amount, linenumber)
select
  dense_rank() over (order by invnum) + 99,
  linetype,
  amount,
  linenumber
from source_table;
```

It's not a good idea, though, to store data redundantly. There shouldn't be a total amount in the header table, as this amount can be selected from the line table entries.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/_b78_f_S